# internet explorer multiple jdk versions

Tags: internet-explorer, plugins, java

Is there a way to switch between multiple versions of JDK/JRE in Internet Explorer ?

Wanted to use jdk 1.4, jdk 5 & jdk 6.

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge this is not easily done, as the Java plugin used by IE is not intended to be versioned, with several versions living next to each other.

If what you need is having several testing environments, it will most likely be cleaner to have a virtual Windows-machine for each specific environment and you can then run your tests in each.